# Change the sysdate value?

Tags: linux, oracle11g

Before I start, I don't speak English very well, so I apologize for any mistakes.

I want to change the `sysdate` value because it is different to the date value of the system. When I execute `"SELECT sysdate FROM dual"`, I get an hour "X", but when I get the date from the system (in the console, I type "date"), I get the date "X" but -12 hours, ex:

```
*Query executed on Toad: SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;

                        -> 09/04/2014 05:18:30

 *In Linux Server shell: date

                        -> Tue Apr  8 17:19:17 CDT 2014
```

What's wrong? I've restarted all instances including the listener, we handle grid infrastructure to our DB on a linux server.

Can I change the sysdate value?

Comment: that makes no sense.  oracle should be using the time from the OS.

Comment: What is your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`? Looks like it might be set to `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI` instead of using `HH24`; or you're using the 12-hour model in a `to_char` call. Is it only 'wrong' in the afternoon?

Comment: I've edited the example, now it shows exactly what I see on my query executed on the Toad and the shell. All day, mornig, afternoon...

Answer (score 2):

You can try following query to get system date in 24 hour formate.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
```